# What is the meaning of "pools of gold" in "Nineteen Eighty-Four"?

Tags: meaning, george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

From the beginning of part 2, chapter 2:

> Winston picked his way up the lane through dappled light and
> shade, stepping out into **pools of gold** wherever the boughs
> parted. Under the trees to the left of him the ground was misty
> with bluebells. The air seemed to kiss one’s skin. It was the second
> of May. From somewhere deeper in the heart of the wood came
> the droning of ring-doves.

What is the meaning of "pools of good"?

Comment: Do you mean what's the artistic significance of him choosing that phrase, or literally what does it mean?  If the latter, it's just a shorter and more poetic way of saying "pools of golden sunlight".  I'd have expected that to be pretty obvious to a fluent English speaker, so is English not your first language?  If so, questions like this may go down better on English Language Learners Stack Exchange.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this is suitable for ELL because there's more going on in this paragraph. In particular, there is a [pathetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy) (that is, the scenery reflecting Winston's emotions).

Answer (score 4):

In terms of explicit imagery, Orwell is referring to the yellow sunlight passing between the trees and making bright patterns on the ground, thusly.

[image]

These similes and metaphors reflect a fairly simple [*'pathetic fallacy'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy), where Winston's mental state change and improvement (in terms of his journey from the grim city into the beautiful countryside where he will be meeting his lover) are demonstrated to the reader by showing them some idyllic [pastoral scenes](https://www.nps.gov/museum/exhibits/landscape_art/exb/Eminent_Americans_At_Home/Pastoral_Landscapes/lgImages/LONG4306.jpg).